# need to remove the entire row when clicking the remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <tr>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Make</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Doors</td>
        <td>4 Wheel Drive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="small_input_text required only_number" name="auto_year_'+no_fields+'" id="auto_year_'+no_fields+'" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small_input_text required" name="auto_make_'+no_fields+'" id="auto_make_'+no_fields+'" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small_input_text required" name="auto_model_'+no_fields+'" id="auto_model_'+no_fields+'" /></td>
        <td>
            <select name="auto_doors_'+no_fields+'" id="auto_doors_'+no_fields+'">
                <option value="2 door">2 door</option>
                <option value="4 door">4 door</option>
             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="auto_liability_'+no_fields+'" id="auto_liability_'+no_fields+'">
                <option value="No">No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="remove_new" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();");">x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
        <ul class="regular_form">
            <li>
            <label class="large_label">Current Liability Limit:</label>
            <input type="text" class="medium_input_text" name="l_exp_date_'+no_fields+'" id="l_exp_date_'+no_fields+'"/>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label class="large_label">Bodily Inj. Liab.:</label>
            <select name="a_body_'+no_fields+'" id="a_body_'+no_fields+'">
                <option value="50/100">50k / 100k</option>
                <option value="100/300">100k / 300k</option>
                <option value="250/500">250k / 500k</option>
            </select>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label class="large_label">Property Damage:</label>
            <select name="a_property">
                <option value="10">10,000</option>
                <option value="25">25,000</option>
                <option value="50">50,000</option>
                <option value="100">100,000</option>
                <option value="100">250,000</option>
            </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="large_label">
                    Uninsured Motorist:</label><select name="a_unins_'+no_fields+'" id="a_unins_'+no_fields+'"><option
                        value="25/50/25">25/50/25</option>
                        <option value="50/100/50">50/100/50</option>
                        <option value="100/300/100">100/300/100</option>
                    </select></li><li>
                        <label class="large_label">
                            Collision:</label><select name="a_col_'+no_fields+'" id="a_col_'+no_fields+'"><option
                                value="250">250 Deductible</option>
                                <option value="500">500 Deductible</option>
                                <option value="1000">1,000 Deductible</option>
                            </select></li><li>
                                <label class="large_label">
                                    Comprehensize:</label><select name="a_comp_'+no_fields+'" id="a_comp_'+no_fields+'"><option
                                        value="0">0 Deductible</option>
                                        <option value="100">100 Deductible</option>
                                        <option value="250">250 Deductible</option>
                                        <option value="500">500 Deductible</option>
                                        <option value="1000">1000 Deductible</option>
                                    </select></li><li>
                                        <label class="large_label">
                                            Rental Car:</label><select name="a_rent_'+no_fields+'" id="a_rent_'+no_fields+'"><option
                                                value="$20/day">$20/day</option>
                                                <option value="$30/day">$30/day</option>
                                            </select></li><li>
                                                <label class="large_label">
                                                    Towing:</label><select name="a_towing"><option value="$100">$50</option>
                                                        <option value="$100">$100</option>
                                                    </select></li></ul>
            <a class="remove_new" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: are theese rows actual table rows or li's??? and source code would be helpful to really understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: can you show some of your codes?

Comment: The bad news is that this was the actual code, without formatting. @Mat, please take the time to format this into something consumable by a human by hitting the `edit` button.

Comment: Hi Mat, here is an example of formatting w/ jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orolo/bnZwg/ (and this version should be improved upon in the html). It's super helpful to paste your code in your question appropriately so the community can actually see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you had a button, link or something inside a `<td>` of the row you want removed, you could do something like the code below.

- The magic is: `$(this).closest('tr').remove()` -- closest will travel up the DOM finding the `tr` element. If you wanted a quick fix for your code, try `onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();"`

### HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Row 1</td>
     <td><input type="button" class="remove_row" value="Remove Row"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Row 2</td>
     <td><input type="button" class="remove_row" value="Remove Row"/></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.remove_row').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**Fiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/ernnP/
Use of `.live` is assuming in the future you want to have a functionality of adding a row.

Answer (score 1):

The only immediate error that I can see in that code is this:

```
onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();");"
```

...you have an extra `);"` at the end. It should be:

```
onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();"
```

It's on <s>the first</s> both `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in your code, let's look at just the removal link

```
<a class="remove_new" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();");">x</a>
```

This should probably be

```
<a class="remove_new" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">x</a>
```

It's probably better to do something along the lines of

```
<a class="remove_new" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">x</a>
```

That way you don't have to depend on the stability of the DOM and it should work, I tried testing it in JsFiddle but something in your code is messing with JsFiddle and it won't import jQuery correctly.

In the future you will probably get an answer more quickly if you nicely format your code and if you can provide a simplified case.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/orolo/bnZwg/

```
$('.remove_new').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```